# Simple server with Thrift and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, ipc, thrift

My current task is to create simple server with Thrift IPC interface based on Qt library.
I have downloaded thrift, compiled, created interface.thrift file and generated stub ( --gen cpp ). Also, I have successfully compiled simple example but all this stuff without Qt.
Now, I need to integrate thrift with Qt, but TQTcpServer wants Async processor !
Inside stub I didn't find any async processor (only TDispatchProcessor).

How to pass processor to TQTcpServer ? Small example will be preferably.

```
TQTcpServer(boost::shared_ptr<QTcpServer> server,
          boost::shared_ptr<TAsyncProcessor> processor,
          boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory,
          QT_PREPEND_NAMESPACE(QObject)* parent = NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution, may be it will be usefull for other

For usage Thrift in Qt you need to create STUB with Async support

```
thrift --gen cpp:cob_style ./your_name.thrift
```

Copy class your_nameAsyncHandler, your_nameHandler from generated STAB to you project

```
boost::shared_ptr<QTcpServer> tcp_server_( new QTcpServer() )
if( !tcp_server_->isListening() && !tcp_server_->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 9090) )
{
    // throw exception
    return;
}

shared_ptr<your_nameAsyncHandler> handler(new your_nameAsyncHandler());
shared_ptr<TAsyncProcessor> processor(new your_nameAsyncProcessor(handler));
shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::async::TQTcpServer> thrift_server_( new apache::thrift::async::TQTcpServer( tcp_server_, processor, protocolFactory) );
```

Comment: I have been looking all day trying to find out how to get Async working.  Why is there no documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what my main looks like, its pretty simple, this is all running on localhost.

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    boost::shared_ptr<QTcpServer> tcp_server_( new QTcpServer() );
    boost::shared_ptr<UserStorageAsyncHandler> handler(new UserStorageAsyncHandler());
    boost::shared_ptr<TAsyncProcessor> processor(new UserStorageAsyncProcessor(handler));
    boost::shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());

    boost::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::async::TQTcpServer> thrift_server_(
                new apache::thrift::async::TQTcpServer( tcp_server_, processor, protocolFactory) );

    if (!tcp_server_->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 27015)) {
        std::cout << "TCP Server not listening" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: looks good ;)  Do you check code inside UserStorageAsyncHandler for errors or dead loops ?